# What is this writing standard called,  and where can I look up the exact details?

Tags: style, essay

My English instructor said that he wants us to submit a heading and a header on our essays, taking the following form.

- The first page only should have our name, his name, the date, the subject (not necessarily in that order) in the top left.
- The top right of every page should have our last name and the page number.

What is that style called? (Is it MLA?) Also, what is the order of the elements of the heading on the first page?

Comment: Sounds like you have a frontispiece for your first page

Comment: @Thursagen - A what?

Comment: Archaic usage of frontispiece means the title page of a work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you've described sounds very much like the [MLA publishing guidelines](http://www.csus.edu/owl/index/mla/mla_format.htm) for essays.

For further information/reference, have a look at the following link:

http://www.mla.org/style_faq1

Answer (score 3):

Be careful with a format given by an instructor. Although it may be MLA, often instructors have specific tweeks they have added to suit their needs. I would ask the instructor if they want you to follow MLA before assuming that format. If the instructor says no and does not offer a name of a format, ask for examples or clarification so you are sure to meet the expectations of the instructor.